# Saving wysiwyg Editor content with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wysiwyg

I am writing a cms (on .net) and have structured the whole page to work client side.
There is a treeview that lets you add/remove/move items and define their names in the languages defined. For each language I save the names of the category defined, but when there is HTML content associated with it, i fall into the JavaScript serializer problem that finds the content too long to be serialized.

What would be the best approach to make sth like this work. Shall I change everything to work with postbacks, or try to manually call _doPostBack for the editor content (which I don't want). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess would be great to make auto-save with time interval which will submit only diffs between current state and previous save. It will do the key if the user will edit it manually, not for copy/paste, of course. It is if we talk about really big data that we need to save.
Otherwise need to find some ways to compress the data before submitting: json+base64, etc.

Comment: cutting it down to chunks for saving will also require to do the same when getting it back from the server. It's gonna be too much work for saving some text under some category kinda thing :)

Comment: Why do you need to get it back by chunks? Use you imagination? Use DOM, compare diffs locally, send it (no need to receive) to server only when it really need to be saved. It is not as hard as you think so.